# Cocos2d-XNA: How to integrate MonoGame

Tags: windows-phone-8, monogame, cocos2d-x-for-xna

I have a confusion regarding Cocos2d-XNA.
Is it already have MonoGame in it? If not, how do I combine those two?
If yes, what is the role of Cocos2d-XNA and what is the role of MonoGame?

I tried to look for both website but not able to find these information.

If needed: I'm trying to build a game in WP8.

Comment: both are render engines, why would you want to combine them?

Comment: hi, it appear that Cocos2d-xna is built on top of MonoGame, so it is already combine to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a installed Cocos2d-XNA template, I found Monogame is in the reference. But only after installing Monogame (except for a Cocos2d-XNA package) the template works.

So I don't think Monogame is in Cocos2d-XNA. But Cocos2d-XNA needs Monogame. To combine them is easy, from my experience, just install Cocos2d-XNA template, Cocos2d-XNA package, Monogame package, and Monogame3.3.
(Install template with a downloaded .vsix file, install packages through NuGet, and install Monogame3.3 with a downloaded .exe file)  And I agree that Cocos2d-XNA is built on the top of Monogame, for Microsoft.Xna.Framework and other XNA things are in Monogame, and Cocos2d-XNA needs those things.